# Add bind mount to Dockerfile just like volume

Tags: docker, containers, docker-volume

I want to add the bind mount to docker file just like I initialise a volume inside Dockefile. 
Is there any way for it?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

A Dockerfile defines how an image is built, not how it's used - so you can't specify the bind mount in a Dockerfile.  Try using [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) instead.  A simple `docker-compose.yml` that mounts a directory for you would look like this:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  mycontainer:
    image: myimage
    build: .
    volumes:
      - './path/on/docker/host:/path/inside/container'
```

The `build: .` is optional if you're building the image by some other means, but sometimes it's handy to do it all in one.

Run this with `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: `-d` isn't required

Comment: how does the volume apply to windows machines - do I use a windows specific path? (windows with linux containers)

Comment: @poige Actually `-d` is required to start the container in detached mode ... Otherwise it just locks up your terminal ...

Comment: @SiddharthSeth so what? Not required still.

Answer (score 32):

In addition to what the other answers say:

Because bind mounts provide access to the host filesystem, allowing them to be embedded into an image would be a huge security risk.  Consider an image that purports to be, say, a web server, but in fact bind mounts your `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` and then sends them off to a remote server.

Or one that bind mounts `/lib/ld-linux.so` and then overwrites it, thus breaking your entire system.

For these reasons, you cannot embed a a bind mount in your Dockerfile.  Similarly, you cannot specify host port mappings, host device access, or any other similar attributes in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 14):

The simple answer is no.

A basic design principle for docker images is portability. Bind mounts are hosts specific since the mounted folder is defined on the host machine. Thus this contradicts the portability requirement for Docker images.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can have a bind mount at build-time with https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mounttypebind

Example Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN --mount=type=bind,source=.,target=/test ls -al /test
```

running it in the same folder with

```
docker buildx build . --progress plain --no-cache
```

will output this

```
#6 0.305 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  1 16:33 .
#6 0.305 drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Oct  1 16:33 ..
#6 0.305 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   76 Oct  1 16:33 Dockerfile
```