# Including docker socket in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

Can we add docker.sock from host to container using Dockerfile? What I want to do is issue docker commands (pull, tag and push) inside container. I know the "-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" in docker run command but I need to include the same inside Dockerfile to build it. Here below is my Dockerfile :-

```
FROM centos:latest
RUN yum update -y && yum install epel-release -y
RUN yum install python-pip -y
RUN pip install requests
COPY docker_push.py /tmp
COPY config.ini /tmp
RUN yum install docker-io -y
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "/tmp/docker_push.py"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it ok to run docker from inside docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879713/is-it-ok-to-run-docker-from-inside-docker)

Answer (score 0):

*Possible duplicate of : [Add bind mount to Dockerfile just like volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942016/add-bind-mount-to-dockerfile-just-like-volume)*

> TL;DR:
>
> A Dockerfile is just a description of how an image is built. The act of binding a volume is host-specific, so it could be defined only when a container will instantiate this image.

As a substitute of passing the argument `-v` at `docker run`, you could also use a [compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) to manage it :

```
version: '3'
services:
  XXXX:
    build: YYYYY
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```